# Schema Unspecified Type

Tags: schema, schema.org, markup, json-ld

I am trying to write some FAQs as structured data, but when using the validator tool, it is telling me that I am using an unspecified schema type. I don't understand how this can be, as I have copied it directly from Google's sample code, and simply changed the content.

```
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "FAQPage",
  "mainEntity": [{
    "@type": "Question",
    "name": "Question Text?",
    "acceptedAnswer": {
      "@type": "Answer",
      "text": "Answer text"
    }
```

[image: error message]

Comment: at the top level you need to specify the context. e.g. "@context": "https://schema.org",

Answer (score 1):

### Invalid JSON

Next time validate your JSON code (Your code throw errors). This is one of the most common JSON errors (Missing closing).

[image]

**Online JSON Formatter and JSON Validator :** https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

`{` and closing `}` & `]` & `}` added. Working example:

```js
{ 
   "@context":"https://schema.org",
   "@type":"FAQPage",
   "mainEntity":[ 
      { 
         "@type":"Question",
         "name":"John doe",
         "acceptedAnswer":{ 
            "@type":"Answer",
            "text":"My answer"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

[image]